# Options for converting between localized strings and datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, localization, formatting

I need to

- parse a localized string to a datetime object,
- use a datetime object to generate a localized string.

The problem is that the default locale ("de_DE") does not match the localized string ("en_US").

[image: sketch of the conversion process]

**What options are there to implement the described conversions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that I have not studied all available libraries and just want to provide a starting point for others to solve their problems.

I will use the following localized string during all examples:

```
dt_str = "Thu 3 Apr 2014 13:19:52"        # en_US
```

---

#### 1. Methods of 'datetime.datetime'

This is the simplest approach, but it becomes unwieldy if you use locales other than the default locale.
Information about the syntax can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str,
                                "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
# datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 3, 13, 19, 52)

s = dt.strftime("%a %-d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
# 'Thu 3 Apr 2014 13:19:52'
```

If you like to parse or format other locales, you have to change the global locale, which could result in undesired side effects. (I do not recommend this approach.)

```
import datetime
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "de_DE.UTF-8")

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("Do 3 Apr 2014 13:19:52",
                                "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
# datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 3, 13, 19, 52)

s = dt.strftime("%a %-d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
# 'Do 3 Apr 2014 13:19:52'
```

#### 2. The python library 'arrow'

[arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) allows you to pass a locale (otherwise it uses "en_US").

```
import arrow        # installed via pip
import datetime

### localized string -> datetime
a_dt = arrow.get(dt_str,
                 "ddd D MMM YYYY H:mm:ss",
                 locale="en_US")                # "en_US" is also the default, so this is just for clarification 

dt = a_dt.datetime
# datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 3, 13, 19, 52, tzinfo=tzutc())


### datetime -> localized string
a_s = arrow.get(datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 17, 14, 0, 0))

s = a_s.format("ddd D MMM YYYY H:mm:ss",
               locale="en_US")                 # "en_US" is also the default, so this is just for clarification
# 'Sat 17 May 2014 14:00:00'
```

This is especially useful if the desired locale differs from the default locale.

[image: sketch of the conversion]

#### 3. The python library 'babel' (mainly for formatting)

The strength of [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) is the formatting (Unfortunately, it seems that [it can not **parse** any pattern](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/432). [Only the format "short" seems reliable](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/541).)

```
import babel.dates    # 'babel' installed via pip
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 3, 13, 19, 52)
# parsing is the problem with babel, therefore I created the datetime object directly.

s = babel.dates.format_datetime(dt,
                                "EEE d MMM yyyy H:mm:ss", 
                                locale="en_US")
# 'Thu 3 Apr 2014 13:19:52'
```

#### 4. The python library 'dateparser' (only parsing)

[dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser) is very powerful. It is able to lookup dates in longer texts and does support non-Gregorian calendar systems, just to name a few features.

```
import dateparser        # installed via pip

dt = dateparser.parse(dt_str,
                      date_formats=["%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"],
                      languages=["en"])
# datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 3, 13, 19, 52)
```

#### 5. Last but not least

The following noteworthy python libraries have great features, but unfortunately I could not use them for this specific problem (or did not know how to use them properly).

- [maya](https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya)
- [delorean](https://delorean.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)
- [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/)